# phantom "cells" below the end of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there any way to control these?  Or make them go away?

Grouped style is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a table footer view to your table -- this stops the empty cells appearing. See docs for UITableView, in particular the `tableFooterView` property.

You could just add a zero height UIView as a footer (effectively making it invisible).